# ¿Hay alguna forma de desactivar "Drag and Drop" en todas las vistas de mi aplicación Android?

Tags: java, android

En el apartado **Errores y ANR** de Google Play Console este error se hace frecuente en usuarios cuyos dispositivos tienen Android 10 o superior.

```
> Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Drag shadow dimensions must
> be positive   at android.view.View.startDragAndDrop (View.java:25464) 
> at android.widget.Editor.startDragAndDrop (Editor.java:1183)   at
> android.widget.Editor.performLongClick (Editor.java:1209)   at
> android.widget.TextView.performLongClick (TextView.java:12292)   at
> android.view.View.performLongClick (View.java:7222)   at
> android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run (View.java:27374)   at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)   at
> android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:241)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7617)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke   at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (RuntimeInit.java:492)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

El mensaje de error no me permite saber el lugar en que el error ocurre, pero, por lo que he investigado parace ser provocado al intentar hacer "Drag and Drop", en este caso en un `TextView`, por lo que dice esta línea del mensaje de error:

```
android.widget.TextView.performLongClick (TextView.java:12292).
```

A mi la funcionalidad de "Drag and Drop" no me interesa. Mis `TextView` permiten lo siguiente y eso sí quiero conservarlo:

1. Seleccionar parte del texto o todo el texto para copiar, pegar, compartir
2. Aumentar o agrandar el tamaño del texto haciendo "Pinch to Zoom", mediante una clase personalizada que extiende de `TextView`
3. Tener enlaces clickeables

Las tres cosas funcionan bien. Entonces, ¿cómo puedo desactivar la posibilidad de "Drag and Drop" de todas mis vistas o de mis TextView, sin evitar que pueda hacer las tres cosas antes mencionadas? Pregunto por *todas mis vistas* porque uso también RecyclerView, Menues, etc y al parecer también en ellos se puede hacer "Drag and Drop", pero es que no me interesa que se haga "Drag and Drop" en ningún caso.

Así es como configuro mi `TextView` en un `Fragment` cualquiera de mi aplicación:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements TextToSpeechCallback {

    private ZoomTextView mTextView;

    private void setConfiguration() {

        mViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        mTextView = binding.include.tvZoomable;
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        float fontSize = Float.parseFloat(prefs.getString("font_size", "18"));
        String fontFamily = String.format(new Locale("es"),"fonts/%s",prefs.getString("font_name", "robotoslab_regular.ttf"));
        Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(requireActivity().getAssets(),fontFamily);
        mTextView .setTypeface(tf);
        mTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize);
        hasInvitatory = prefs.getBoolean("invitatorio", false);
        isVoiceOn = prefs.getBoolean("voice", true);
        if (isVoiceOn) {
            sbReader = new StringBuilder(VOICE_INI);
        }
    }
    
    // ...

}
```

Y el XML de mi `TextView` es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_preferences"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
    >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.example.utils.ZoomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_Zoomable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="50dp"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppTheme.DisplayBody"
                />
        </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

¿Hay algún modo de desactivar la posibilidad de "Drag and Drop", sea desde el XML, sea de forma programática?

Comment: ¿Usas `View.DragShadowBuilder`? ¿Cómo lo usas?

Comment: @Mateo no uso nada, ni siquiera sé di debo hacerlo directamente en el `TextView`, en la vista, etc.